# Outputing Text to a Textbox in a webClient.DownloadFile loop

Tags: c#, textbox, webclient

I wasn't sure how to phrase my question.  I'm trying to download 500 csv files in a foreach loop and I'm having errors with something I'm downloading.  So I put a .text output before and after each webClient.DownloadFile call.  Problem is it doesn't seem to output each .text file as I go; if it is successful it will output them all at the end, if it fails it won't output any.  There is some thread/priory thing I'm not aware of.  Can anyone help me do what I'm trying to do?  Thanks (noob in this area).  Below is my code.

```
foreach (var ticker in tickers)
    {
        tbOutput.Text += "Starting Download of : " + ticker + "\n";

        var url = string.Format(urlPrototype, ticker, startMonth, startDay, startYear, finishMonth, finishDay, finishYear, "d");
        var csvfile = directory + "\\" + ticker.ToUpper() + ".csv";

        webClient.DownloadFile(url, csvfile);

        tbOutput.Text += "End Download of : " + ticker + "\n";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It hard to say what technology you are sung but you are most likely calling an event or a post-back, so you get result after full execution, if you want to see the progress of every file you download you can try to use somethink like

[WebClient.DownloadFileCompleted Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.downloadfilecompleted%28v=vs.110%29.aspx/)

Answer (score 0):

Try can DownloadFile as it would throw WebException.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ez801hhe%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

```
foreach (var ticker in tickers)
{
    tbOutput.Text += "Starting Download of : " + ticker + "\n";

    var url = string.Format(urlPrototype, ticker, startMonth, startDay, startYear, finishMonth, finishDay, finishYear, "d");
    var csvfile = directory + "\\" + ticker.ToUpper() + ".csv";

    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((o) =>
    {
        try
        {
            webClient.DownloadFile(url, csvfile);
            System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
            {
                //do something or output like
                tbOutput.Text += "End Download of : " + ticker + " (OK)\n";
            }));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
            {
               //do something or output like
               tbOutput.Text += "End Download of : " + ticker + " (FAIL)\n";
            }));
        }
        finally
        {
            System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
            {
                //do something or output like
                //tbOutput.Text += "End Download of : " + ticker + "\n";
            }));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel; the try/catch did get me to find the error files I was having.  I still would like to figure out a way to have the tbOutput.Text print out every time I download a file, instead of waiting to print them all out when its done with the foreach loop... I've been searching not sure if I need to do multithreading.  I've tried to wrap the webClient.Download in a Dispatcher.Invoke... doesn't change anything.  I'm skating on ground I don't understand :)

Comment: You can use ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem to run DownloadFile and Invoke UI action. Another option is to use WebClient.DownloadFileAsync http://www.csharp-examples.net/download-files/.

Comment: I got an error when I tried DownloadFileAsync; using the code example you linked; think it has to do with downloading too many files too fast.  I tried to add a thread sleep but that didn't fix it.  I also tried ThreadPool but that's way over my pay grade; I think I might just let this one go and look at it later since I'm up and running.  I would think there would be an example of code where you click a button, it downloads a bunch of files, and prints out when each files is done, but I cant find it.

Comment: Then, instead of a textbox to show the file download, you need a listbox to list out what you have download.